# scrollToTop is not working on iPhone but it is working on iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have two view controller. One scrollview for page control and one for detail (scroll vertical).

When i click status bar on iPhone the scrollToTop not working, and in iPad the scrollToTop is working.

I am sure that the scrollView.scrollToTop is YES. because i already print it.

Anyone know what cause the iPhone scrollToTop not working?

Thank you

Edit:
I try by calling the scrollView delegate.
in iPad this delegate its called.
- (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

in iPhone it is not called. 
I already use both 
    contentScrollView.delegate = self; 
But the iphone not working :(

Edit: Try subclassing UIWindow (not working)

Window.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Window : UIWindow
@end
```

Window.m

```
 #import "Window.h"

 @implementation Window

 - (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
if ([event type] == UIEventTypeTouches && point.y < 250) {
    //Send Your Notification Here
    NSLog(@"KAROOO");
}
NSLog(@"HELLOWW");
return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
@end
```

AppDelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet Window *window;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize window = _window;
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand you have 2 UIScrollViews simultaneously on screen.

From what I have seen & experienced,
On iOS 4 having 2 UIScrollViews side by side gives undefined behaviour. One of the scrollview may scroll, sometimes other, sometimes neither.

On iOS 5 if you have 2 UIScrollViews side by side then tapping on status bar "scrolls to top" the UIScrollView right "under your tap"

I don't know how this works, but this has been my observation. iOS 5 is smart !!

If your UIScrollViews are one above other then probably the behaviour is undefined. I haven't checked.

Hope this helps.

If you want to get it working anyways then here is a possible solution.

Subclass <strike>or Add a category on</strike> UIWindow and add a gesture recognizer / or implement hitTest that detects tap only for Y < 20 and so on and then have it send a notification and listen to this in your viewController and programmatically scroll the UIScrollView to top.

**EDIT**

Implement this in the UIWindow subclass (iPad)

```
- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([event type] == UIEventTypeTouches && point.y < 20 && [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        NSLog(@"Portrait");
    } else if ([event type] == UIEventTypeTouches && point.y > 1004 && [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        NSLog(@"PortraitUpsideDown");
    } else if ([event type] == UIEventTypeTouches && point.x < 20 && [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        NSLog(@"LandscapeLeft");
    } else if ([event type] == UIEventTypeTouches && point.x > 748 && [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"LandscapeRight");
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: in my iPhone ios 5 is not working also. in ipad both 4.3 and 5 is working. how can i add a category on UIWindow and add gesture recognizer?

Comment: i have edited my question with uiwindow subclass. Is that correct? if the code is correct, the nslog is not printed.

Comment: I just checked. It worked for portrait orientation but not for others. Looks like UIWindow coordinate system does not change upon orientation. But fixing that shouldn't be a problem. I ll post updated code.

Also I see you are using IBOutlet for Window. You will need to change the class in interface builder as well.

Comment: Updated code. The NSLog prints thrice though since hitTest is called thrice (I don't know why) even for single touch so you need to make sure notification doesn't fire thrice.  
But that should be easy to deal with using the functions  performSelector:afterDelay & cancelPreviousPerformRequest

Comment: hit test is working both iphone and ipad, and print nslog.. however the problem still persist for scrollToTop. it does not work for iphone :( for my problem

Comment: This Hit-Test code will only give you the event of tap on status bar area. It won't automatically scrollToTop your views. You need to use that event and programmatically scrollToTop.
Fire a NSNotification and listen in your viewcontroller. Then scroll the UIScrollView to top by setting contentOffset = 0

Comment: Because i have 5 tab, and each tab has that Scroll View structure. if i use notification, does it will call notification from that 5 view controller? And to make contentOffset of scroll, is this the correct one?     contentScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0 );

Answer (score 1):

In case you have more then one `UIScrollView` instance (including subclasses e.g. `UITableView` e.t.c) on the same screen you need to define wich one should act on scrollToTop event. That means, that you need to go through those instances and set their `scrollToTop` property to NO except for the one you do want to do so. For me it worked always. In case it didn't, it was because of some other `UIScrollView` that I didn't knew it's there. In that case I just walked throug all subviews recursively disabling thet property and then it started to work as espected.
Cheers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what Apple were smoking but by design, the behaviour on iPhone is distinctly different from iPad.  [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/scrollsToTop) does include a "Special Condsideration" note as follows...

> On iPhone, the scroll-to-top gesture has no effect if there is more
>   than one scroll view on-screen that has scrollsToTop set to YES.

So on iPhone you have to ensure that there is only ever one UIScrollView (or UITableView/UICollectionView/UIWebView etc) that has its `scrollsToTop = YES`.

Since scrollsToTop defaults to YES you have to explicitly set `scrollsToTop = NO` for the UIScrollView's you do not want to scroll when the user taps the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution based on NSIntegerMax's answer. This way we don't have to care about the orientation or have hardcoded values.

declare this macro

```
#define isInStatusBar(frame, point) (point.x >= frame.origin.x && point.x <= (frame.origin.x+frame.size.width) && point.y >= frame.origin.y && point.y <= (frame.origin.y+frame.size.height))
```

and implement the method:

```
- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGRect frame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];

    if ([event type] == UIEventTypeTouches && isInStatusBar(frame, point)) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationAppDidTouchStatusBar object:nil];
    }

    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```