# UIScrollViews won't scroll to top on my app structure

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

First of all, sorry about my english.

I have an issue with the scroll views of my app. I know that I can have only one scroll view per view controller in order to avoid problems with the "tap the status bar to scroll to the top"; and I have only one per VC, but all the VC are inside a bigger one, that handles the view sizes and the interface orientation. This is the structure:

- Main View Controller

  - Page 1 (View controller)
  - Page 2 (View controller)
    ...

And the only scroll view that works with the status bar is one inside a UITableView on the **Page 1**.

Finally, the question: Anyone knows how to fix this issue without changing the main structure of the app? (there are a lot of pages).

Thanks in advance, and really sorry if I made some noob mistake :P.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question.

[scrollToTop is not working on iPhone but it is working on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542122/scrolltotop-not-working-on-iphone-but-working-on-ipad)

Since you cannot change the design of your app take the UIWindow subclass / category approach and do the scrolling yourself

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try the category and the hit test, and if it works I'll check this answer as correct.

Regards