# UIScrollView scrollToTop not getting called for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a universal app, the code is the same. I have a UIScrollView in which has the scrollToTop working on the iPad but not on iPhone. I am pretty frustrated by this.

I know there's a similar thread posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542122/scrolltotop-is-not-working-on-iphone-but-it-is-working-on-ipad), but that is not the case. I used to have the scrolling to work before this both on the iPad and iPhone.  Any idea what to look for?

The structure of the code is like this. I have a mainVC called A. I then have a VC called B. There is also another VC called C, which has a UIScrollView. I added C as B's child view controller. and then B as A's child VC. Now the scroll view on C did not have the scrollToTop working.

The delegate scrollViewShouldScrollToTop is also called only in the iPad, not in the iPhone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [scrollToTop is not working on iPhone but it is working on iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542122/scrolltotop-is-not-working-on-iphone-but-it-is-working-on-ipad)

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist ys I already mentioned it above and I've read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542122/scrolltotop-is-not-working-on-iphone-but-it-is-working-on-ipad/11549980#11549980) to the question you've talked about. I've just added it a moment ago.

***EDIT***

I don't have the original code I've made, but it should be like that:

```
-(void)cleanUp:(UIScrollView*)view{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
        view.scrollsToTop = NO;
    }else{
        for(UIScrollView* subview in view.subviews){
            if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]){
                [self cleanUp:subview];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and you can call it like this:

```
[self cleanUp:self.view];
```

You may also need even more tough variant of that routine (sometimes you may have a tableView inside a scrollView or something like that):

```
-(void)cleanUp:(UIScrollView*)view{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
        view.scrollsToTop = NO;
    }
    for(UIScrollView* subview in view.subviews){
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]){
            [self cleanUp:subview];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I Just took the solution of @Ariel and done some improvements I want to share with you:

```
+ (void)globalDisableScrollToTop:(UIView *)_view;
{
    // Check whether we got a scroll view
    if ([_view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
    {
        // Disable scroll to top
        ((UIScrollView *)_view).scrollsToTop = NO;
    }

    // Iterate all subviews
    for (UIView *view in _view.subviews)
    {
        // Recursive call of this method
        [self globalDisableScrollToTop:view];
    }
}
```

Or without comments:

```
+ (void)globalDisableScrollToTop:(UIView *)_view;
{
    if ([_view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
        ((UIScrollView *)_view).scrollsToTop = NO;

    for (UIView *view in _view.subviews)
        [self globalDisableScrollToTop:view];
}
```

It now fixes all subviews and could be implemented as static method (of your root scroll view class).

Answer (score 0):

If possible, Please paste the add subview code here. Looks like the problem is the view on which the scrollview is present is getting hide behind other view. Try changing the sequence of adding subview. Or you may also try bringSubviewtoFront property for setting the scrollview on top.

Let me know if it helps.